# Difference between /etc/hosts and /etc/resolv.conf

Tags: linux, networking, domain-name-system, internal-dns, linux-networking

What is the difference between /etc/hosts and /etc/resolv.conf? Also, is there a good documentation that explain all these configuration files.

Thank you.
Bala

Answer (score 32, accepted):

`resolv.conf` specifies the nameservers for resolver lookups, where it will actually use the DNS protocol for resolving the hostnames.
Typically the `hosts` file is used for administrative purposes, such as backend and internal functions, which is substantially more isolated in scope, as only the local server will reference it.

`/etc/nsswitch.conf` specifies the lookup order with the `hosts` entry.

If this does not answer your question, please clarify further.

Look at the following manpages:

```
HOSTS(5)  
RESOLVER(5)
```

Comment: http://linux.die.net/man/5/resolver - http://linux.die.net/man/5/hosts

Answer (score 18):

resolv.conf specifies nameservers in order of search preference.

hosts overrides all nameservers by mapping urls/shortnames to IPs.

Answer (score 18):

- **/etc/resolv.conf**: Lists nameservers that are used by your host for
  DNS resolution. If you are using `DHCP`, this file is automatically
  populated with DNS record issued by `DHCP` server.
- **/etc/hosts/**: It is just a static lookup method for resolution.
- **/etc/nsswitch.con**f: It defined order of resolution. Who should it consult first for resolution, a DNS or a host file? For example, if the file has following configuration `hosts: files dns` then `/etc/hosts` file will be checked first for resolution, if domain is still un-resolvable, DNS will then be consulted.

Answer (score 0):

**`/etc/hosts`**: Mapping between IP addresses & hostnames, for name resolution.

```
127.0.0.1 localhost.localdomain localhost
10.2.3.4 myhost.domain.org myhost
```

**`/etc/nsswitch.conf`**: Sources that must be used by various system library lookup functions.

```
passwd: files nisplus nis
shadow: files nisplus nis
group: files nisplus nis
hosts: files dns nisplus nis
```

**`/etc/resolv.conf`**: Domain names that must be appended to bare hostnames, and DNS servers that will be used for name resolution.

```
search domain1.org domain2.org
nameserver 192.168.3.3
nameserver 192.168.4.4
```